# Cannot add JSON response to realm

Tags: ios, swift2, realm, alamofire

I'm trying to add my POST response to realm but I am thrown this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Object'

This is my code:

```
     Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.loginEndpoint, parameters: parameters)
        .responseObject { (response: Response<Particulars, NSError>) in

            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.result)


            if let result = response.result.value
            {

                do{
                    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)
                    let realm = try Realm()
                    realm.add(result.name, update: true)
                }

                catch let err as NSError {
                    print("Error with realm: " + err.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
            else
            {
                print("JSON data is nil. 123")
            }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I am getting this error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

at `user.name = result["name"]!.string`

Also, I'd like to remove `!` from my `do{} catch{}` but swift won't allow me to do so. How do I fix it?

My code:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.loginEndpoint, parameters: parameters)
        .responseObject { (response: Response<Particulars, NSError>) in

            print(response.request)
            print(response.response)
            print(response.result)



            if let result = response.result.value
            {

                do{
                    let user = Particulars()
                    user.name = result["name"]!.string
                    user.apiToken = result["api_token"]!.string
                    let realm = try Realm()
                    realm.add(user, update: true)
                    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)
                }

                catch let err as NSError {
                    print("Error with realm: " + err.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
            else
            {
                print("JSON data is nil. 123")
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Realm but it looks like Realm is wanting a class object that inherits from Its 'Object' type. I would imagine that you have to create a class object with all of the properties you need (name, email, etc) set those properties when you get a response and then save that object to Realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet is pulled straight from the Realm docs. Realm is wanting a class object that inherits from Its 'Object' type. You have to create a class object with all of the properties you need (name, email, etc) set those properties when you get a response and then save that object to Realm.

```
class Dog: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var age = 0
}
class Person: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var picture: NSData? = nil // optionals supported
  let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

// Use them like regular Swift objects
let myDog = Dog()
myDog.name = "Rex"
myDog.age = 1
print("name of dog: \(myDog.name)")

// Get the default Realm
let realm = try! Realm()

// Query Realm for all dogs less than 2 years old
let puppies = realm.objects(Dog).filter("age < 2")
puppies.count // => 0 because no dogs have been added to the Realm yet

// Persist your data easily
try! realm.write {
   realm.add(myDog)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Richmond I've tried this but I'm getting thrown a few errors (see updated post). Can you please help me?

Comment: Looks like you don't have a value for the "name" key in your JSON. I suggest reading up on Optionals. You have to use the '!' because ` result["name"]` is an Optional. That means it can either be nil or not nil. In your case it is nil. When you use the '!' you are telling it to show its true value. In your case the value is nil and yet you are still calling `.string`. Since you are calling `.string` on a nil object an exception is being thrown

Comment: But I am able to get an output when I do a print result so it shouldnt be nil